# How to get page access token Facebook graph api via calling the get request, java

Tags: java, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am trying to get a page access token of a facebook page using its graph api for posting anything in that page.

From https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer    I can get the page access token and then I can post on the page using it.

I go through all the similar question answer of stack overflow. but failed.

Here is my details flow

1. Firstly for code - my_code
   `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=&redirect_uri=&scope=email`
2. I get the user_access_token going through this

   `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=my_app_id&client_secret=my_app_secret&redirect_uri=my_redirect_url&code=my_code`
3. Then for long lived token

   `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=my_app_id&client_secret=my_app_secret&fb_exchange_token=my_user_access_token`
4. After getting the my_user_access_token_long I request for page access token

   `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=my_user_access_token_long`

   it returns

   `{"data":[]}`

   If I try    `https://graph.facebook.com/my_page_id?fields=access_token&access_token=my_access_token_long`

   it returns only my page id

   {
   "id": "my_page_id"
   }

**Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You did not ask the user for the permission that is necessary to create a page access token.

Comment: to CBroe : The page is public page. If so then how can I asked for permission ?

Comment: You can not get a page access token for pages that your user does not have admin rights to.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `manage_pages` permission in the first step

`http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=&redirect_uri=&scope=email,manage_pages`

See [Page Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you phwd I got  now Page Access Token. But now I am getting forbidden while I am posting anything on the page.

While getting me/accounts I am having this permission for the page  `"perms":[
"ADMINISTER",
"EDIT_PROFILE",
"CREATE_CONTENT",
"MODERATE_CONTENT",
"CREATE_ADS",
"BASIC_ADMIN"
]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this critical page being mentioned:

[Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)

This shows the whole required OAuth flow, and how to exchange a temporary code after the user authenticates, with a final longer-term access token (from what I am seeing, with an expiration at this time of ~ 60 days).